# How to extract the contents of the mth column of the nth row from a csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I created a CSV file and was able to add headers for it. I tried using loc to extract the contents but to no avail.

I want to get *e* as an output or use it in code for something.

The code I've used is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
with open("boo.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(('a','b', 'c'))
df = pd.read_csv("boo.csv", header=None)
df.to_csv("boo.csv", header=["alpha", "beta", "gamma"], index=False)
with open('boo.csv','a') as f: 
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(('c','d','e'))
    writer.writerow(('f','g','h'))
print(df.loc[(df["alpha"]=='c')]["gamma"])
```

Upon running this code, I'm getting a KeyError for *alpha*. Please help with this. I'm pretty new to handling CSV files and pandas.

Thank you. :)

Comment: You wrote the dataframe to a csv, but never read that data back in. Therefore your headers exist in the csv, but not your current dataframe. Before you print at the end of your snippet, try: `df = pd.read_csv("boo.csv")` to read your updated data w/ the headers.

Comment: @CameronRiddell thank you for your help. I was able to get just e by taking the [1]th element from the extracted thing! :)